# Internationalize nodejs jade templates

Tags: node.js, express, internationalization, pug

I'm trying to internationalize my nodejs express app using i18n-2 module. All is working but I have a question. Is there a way to translate string from my jade templates. Imagine I have 100 strings in my website. Do I have to send 100 translations to the template through the res.render invocation?

```
res.render('profile', {
  title: 'My cool title',
  user: req.user,
  hello1: req.i18n.__("hello1"),
  hello2: req.i18n.__("hello2"),
  hello3: req.i18n.__("hello3"),
  ...
  helloN: req.i18n.__("helloN")
});
```

Is there another way to do this? Somethin like the next code:

```
res.render('profile', {
  title: 'My cool title',
  user: req.user,
  i18n: req.i18n // to be used inside jade
});
```

Comment: Seems like you answered your own question. Did you already try passing `req.i18n` to the jade template and using it within the template?

Comment: Yeah, I tried. In jade I get errors when I try to this #{i18n.__('hello1')}. I I only put i18n.__('hello1') this is the text printed.

Comment: Can you prepare a Fiddle so I can see what you're doing?

Comment: Here you have some code: app.js http://pastie.org/9622496 and route/jade http://pastie.org/9622504

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i18n-2 already registers helper objects in your Express locals, which are accessible form your Jade template. These helper methods are registered automatically: "__", "__n", "getLocale", and "isPreferredLocale". Without any additional configuration, should be able to do the following in your Jade template:

```
a(href="/") #{ __('home') }
```